# Do we want a blog?

Tags: discussion

There is an opportunity to have a blog about Russian, this site, or both.

**Do we want to have a blog?**

If yes, who would like to contribute to it? The more people we have, the easier it gets for us to update the blog reasonably often.

Here are some of the things we could write in the blog:

- Discuss most interesting questions
- Interview users about their point of view on some topic
- Cover events that are important for the Russian language and its usage
- Discuss questions from meta site
- and you can find more ideas [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/blog-overflow/)

So far, Alenanno, Quassnoi and myself are ready each to write a post for the blog once in several weeks.

I think that writing would be a great experience and an opportunity to get to know each other better. What do you say?

Comment: I think I'd be better at writing technical stuff about the site, but if I have some idea about Russian language... Why not? :)

Answer (score 1):

**List of participants**

The topics would be both Russian and the site's technical aspect. Note that the blog is going to start only if **at least** 8 people will sign. But the more, the better! If you're unsure of what is this blog going to be, feel free to comment.

People who are willing to write an article now and then (regularly but with turns):

- Alenanno (occasionally)
- Olga
- Quassnoi
- Aleks G
- theUg
- petajamaja

Comment: How often do you think we need to update the blog?

Comment: If we get 8 people, each one of us will post once every 2 months. I mean, take 8 people, one post each week, so... You'll post not so often.

Comment: I'm willing to write an article once in a while, as long as there's no "10-printed pages minimum length" or similar.

Comment: @AleksG Of course not, although I'd expect something at least medium so someone has something to read. :) I don't mind if it's 1 or 10 pages, as long as there is something to read. Less than half a page would be too little, though.

Comment: Fair enough.  I'm in then.

Comment: @AleksG Great! :)

Comment: Add me in too. It’s not that I have a lot to say, but I am willing to help, and to practise my college writing skills. :) We could gather sometimes and discuss topics we could delegate and explore. We could even do it openly in chat to get some interest from other people.

Comment: Hey, I'll probably join you too. I used to like writing essays at school. But what we should consider is **choosing an editor (one of moderators probably)**. I think that articles should be reviewed before posting (e.g. I have a huge amount of small mistakes in English that will not be welcome by native speakers!)

Comment: OK, what I know is that I am able to write article reviews (but NOT good at looking for them - all my dictionaries and books are left at home in SPb and now I mostly rely on other users),popularizing some topics related to historical development of Russian language (example: how Russian fairy tales influenced it), anything about people (really wish to try interviewing users!)

Comment: If you wish to write the article in Russian, I doubt there'd be a problem... I don't know if there are constraints there, I'll ask about it.

Comment: No, English is OK, I only wanted to tell you that I might spoil the impression from the site. However, I may try to write as grammatically correct as I can.

Comment: Hm sorry, from now on my nick will be petajamaja ( found out that the previous one was translated from Japanese not in the way I expected o_O). Could you please change it in the list? Otherwise I am Natalia outside the net.

Comment: @petajamaja Done. :)

Comment: @Alennano thanks a lot =) How are things with the blog?

Comment: @petajamaja Uhm static. :P

Answer (score 0):

It's been two months since we raised this question.  So far we have four people willing to write a piece once in a while.  As @Olga pointed out, we need at least 8 to get started. I'd like to understand whether people are simply not interested in a blog or are not interested in writing for the blog.  Or, maybe, not enough people visit `meta` and just haven't seen this question?

Comment: Maybe a bit of everything... :) Some people don't visit Meta and some of those who do, don't feel like doing something.

Comment: I'm afraid, meta is not popular. Even featured questions only get about 10 views per day.

Comment: AleksG, Alenanno and @Quassnoi If we are only 4, how do you think, should we create a blog that is rarely updated rather than create no blog at all? I am all in favour of a blog, even if it is only updated occasionally and with 1-2 page texts. I hope that it might attract more visitors and also more volonteer bloggers from the users. Once they see that it's actually simple and all organized, people might get more willing to participate. For that matter, I'll write the first entry =)

Comment: @Olga Provided among the four of us we can get started, I believe we should.  This will provide more visibility of the blog to those users that don't read meta (and I'm sure there are those).

Comment: Well, I think a blog is a very good idea (have you launched it yet?), but I am a bit afraid of taking part because : a) I am a university student with deadline problem - it may occur that my article won't be ready in time;  b) I don't think that I am professional enough to write a real article; c) I have almost no idea what to write about: I mean, for this I must be aware of the latest news in linguistics, but I hardly know any publications etc available online.

Comment: @Umari: I offered help as well, and I have similar limitations, but I think we could discuss topics in chat and someone could volunteer and pick a topic they most like.

Comment: Yes, @theUg, it is certainly better! Do I understand it correctly: people offer a topic in topic stack, once someone picks it up it is removed. Upvotes count if the article is welcome on the blog or not. In this case, I think I could try =) It's so interesting

Comment: @Umari, that is a good idea too. I was just thinking about kicking around ideas in chat. By the way, if we would have a separate blog room like EL&U has, we could just star messages we like most to pick best topics.

Comment: @theUg: I actually prefer your idea, it is faster, and more constructive, and doesn't involve any reputation changes. I don't think it is good to gain reputation points by setting up a voting campaign.